# How to make TabBarView work within CustomScrollView?

Tags: flutter

I have an AppBar with its bottom is TabBar so the first thing I put on my CustomScrollView would be

- SliverAppBar

then I want the body to be TabBarView so I have a thought to put my TabBarView with SliverToBoxAdapter but then the problem arise as the content of the TabBar is a grid that cover the remaining of the viewport I will simply get error if I place it within TabBarView that has infinite height constraints so I decide to put the second sliver on my CustomScrollView with

- SliverAppBar
- SliverFillRemaining

It solve above problem by limiting my TabBarView to the size of the remaining viewport however another problem pop up because now I have 2 different scrollable widget, the sliver one and the non sliver one, if I scroll the grid my (sliver) AppBar won't react since it's not the main scroll widget.

I want the (sliver) AppBar to shrink even if the one get scrolled is just a GridView within TabBarView how to do that?

Answer (score -2):

```
CustomScrollView(
  controller: _scrollViewController,
  slivers: [
    SliverAppBar(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff191919),
      shadowColor: Color(0xff191919),
      elevation: 10,
      forceElevated: true,
      expandedHeight: 87,
      collapsedHeight: 57,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
          bottom: Radius.circular(12),
        ),
      ),
      floating: true,
      pinned: true,
      snap: true,
      stretch: false,
      primary: false,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      title: Text('Title of Header'),
      bottom: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0),
        child: TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Tab(
              text: 'Tab One',
                     
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Tab Two',
                     
            ),
            
          ],
          isScrollable: true,
          indicatorColor: Color(0xffe10d37),
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
          labelColor: Color(0xfff1f1f1),
          indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3),
          
        ),
      ),
    ),
    SliverFillRemaining(
      child: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          _widgetOne,
          _widgetTwo
        ]
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

Comment: Did you even test it before answer the question? It won't even run in dartpad, after I tinker it a bit the problem seems likely to be in SliverAppBar.